# Accessing linked list in a function - C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

My problem  is that i want to access the linked list that i created in the `letters` function, and use it to print it out in the `report` function. However it seems that i can't do that and when i try to check the memory addresses of `chars` and `lst_ptr` i see that the differ from each other. Shouldn't they be the same in order to achieve my goal ?
Thanks in advance !!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct charact {
   char ch;
   int occurs;
   struct charact *next;
};
typedef struct charact Char;

typedef Char * ListofChar;

typedef Char * CharNode_ptr;

void letters(char name[50], ListofChar * chars_ptr);

void report(ListofChar  chars);

Char * createnode(char ch);

int main() {
    char name[50];
    ListofChar chars = NULL;
    scanf("%s", name);
    letters(name, &chars);
    report(chars);
    return 0;
}
Char * createnode(char ch) {
    CharNode_ptr newnode_ptr ;
    newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof (Char));
    newnode_ptr -> ch = ch;
    newnode_ptr -> occurs = 0;
    newnode_ptr -> next = NULL;
    return newnode_ptr;
}
void letters(char name[50], ListofChar * lst_ptr) {
    int i,j,occs;
    lst_ptr=malloc(100);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(name);i++){
        occs=0;
        for(j=0;j<strlen(name);j++){
            if(name[i]==name[j]){
                occs++;
            }
        }
        lst_ptr[i]=createnode(name[i]);
        lst_ptr[i]->occurs=occs;
        if(i>0){
            lst_ptr[i-1]->next=lst_ptr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%p\n",lst_ptr);
    return;
}
void report(ListofChar  chars) {
    printf("%p",chars);
return;
}
```

Comment: The function `letters` never returns the address of the memory it allocated. Assigning a value to an argument, `lst_ptr`, does not send the value back to the caller. Your function must either return a value (a pointer) or accept an argument that is the address of a pointer (not a pointer, but rather the address of a pointer) and then put the new value in that pointer (put the new value in the place where the address points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just discovered what it's like to mess around with pointers :)

So first off, don't `typedef` pointer types with names that don't also have an asterisk in them; else readability will suffer. Indeed I had hard time following your code at first, because of this.

For the reason above, in this answer I'll be pretending that `typedef Char * ListofChar` and `typedef Char * CharNode_ptr` were not there and use just `Char` instead.

In your `main` function you have the following declaration:

```c
Char* chars = NULL;
```

What you need to keep in mind is that the pointer `chars` has itself a memory address. `chars`, however, is pointing to `NULL`.

Now, in your `letters` function you need to modify what `chars` is pointing to. You can achieve this in two ways: either by referring to it from within the function directly like this

```c
void letters(char name[50]) {
    /* ... */

    chars = malloc(100);

    /* ... */
}
```

or by passing `char`'s address to `letters`, thus enabling `letters` to modify what `chars` is pointing to

```c
void letters(char name[50], Char** lst_ptr) {
    /* ... */

    // Note that I'm referring to what lst_ptr is pointing to,
    // that is, chars. At this point of the code, *lst_ptr == chars
    *lst_ptr = malloc(100);

    /* ... */
}
```

Now look at the signature of the functions `report` and `letters`. The former is taking only a pointer (`Char*`) and the latter is taking a pointer to a pointer (`Char**`). This is the reason why your `printf`s give you different locations in memory.
The `printf` in `report` is printing what `chars` is pointing to; while the `printf` in `letters` is printing the address of `chars` (which is held by `lst_ptr`).

In order to print the same address, print what `lst_ptr` is pointing to, that is:

```c
printf("%p\n", *lst_ptr);
```

I took the code you posted and applied what I've just said and this is the output on my machine

```c
gianluca
0x55b67d7db6e0
0x55b67d7db6e0
```